# How do I use Spreadsheet.setSpreadsheetLocale?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, locale

I'm trying to change the Locale for my spreadsheet, but setSpreadsheetLocale doesn't seem to work.

If I do

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
ss.setSpreadsheetLocale('en_AU');
Browser.msgBox(ss.getSpreadsheetLocale());
```

the message box displays the correct locale, but the format of the dates in the sheet doesn't change.  Also, 'File', 'Spreadsheet settings...' still displays the previous locale.
And if I close the spreadsheet and reopen it, it is still in the original locale.

Is it something I'm doing wrong, or is it a bug?

**EDIT** following Serge insas comment : Indeed, refreshing the page (F5) does update the display using the new Locale.

Comment: I'm afraid you're right... it seems to be a bug. btw, I tested 'ss.setSpreadsheetTimeZone('GMT+02');' and I could not get any result either (apart from having getSpreadsheetTimeZone() returning the right value)

Comment: Following Eric's answer, could you please update this post if you meet success on this ? thx

Comment: Thanks ! I starred this ... and raised another issue for the Time Zone defect as well ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the spreadsheet doesn't respect the new locale setting until you refresh the page, while changing it in the UI causes it to go into effect immediately. You can open a bug report on the [issue tracker](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/list) to track this issue.

Comment: Thanks for the link - bug reported.

Answer (score 1):

My workaround was to use the `copyTo()` method to move a sheet in a spreadsheet with the right settings to a new (just created) spreadsheet.

This way, the new spreadsheet inherits the settings.